# Operand should contain 1 column(s) on sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this error when i tried to insert the second field "e.occured_at" On my sub query, I would like select both the field in this table, any idea for fix it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
inbox_msg.id_conversation
), users.name, users.surname, users.username, n. * , image_upload.name_image, (

SELECT e.message, e.occured_at
FROM inbox_msg e
WHERE e.id_user = inbox_msg.id_user
ORDER BY occured_at DESC 
LIMIT 1
) AS last_msg
FROM (

SELECT * 
FROM inbox_join
WHERE (
id_user =1 || id_user_2 =1
)
)n
INNER JOIN inbox_msg ON n.id_conversation = inbox_msg.id_conversation
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = inbox_msg.id_user
INNER JOIN image_upload ON image_upload.id_image = users.profile_image
WHERE inbox_msg.id_user <>1
ORDER BY n.occured_at DESC
```

Comment: The subquery stands for one field in the query, and I don't think it can be several fields. The easiest would be to include 2 subqueries, one for e.message, one for e.occured_at. There might be a way to avoid subqueries since the table inbox_msg is already in your FROM clause but not sure not knowing the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery needs one column to make an alias and you have provided two columns either solution  is to do subquery twice for each column like

```
(
SELECT e.message
FROM inbox_msg e
WHERE e.id_user = inbox_msg.id_user
ORDER BY occured_at DESC 
LIMIT 1
) AS last_msg,
(
SELECT e.occured_at
FROM inbox_msg e
WHERE e.id_user = inbox_msg.id_user
ORDER BY occured_at DESC 
LIMIT 1
) AS last_msg_time
```

Other solution to concat the columns

```
(
SELECT CONCAT(e.message, ' At ', e.occured_at)
FROM inbox_msg e
WHERE e.id_user = inbox_msg.id_user
ORDER BY occured_at DESC 
LIMIT 1
) AS last_msg
```